# php equals regular expression

Tags: php

I know I can use preg_match but I was wondering if php had a way to evaluate to a regular expression like:

```
if(substr($example, 0, 1) == /\s/){ echo 'whitespace!'; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP *does not* have first-class regular expressions.

You will need to use the functions provided by the default [PCRE extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).  Sorry.  It's a backslash-escaping nightmare, but it's all we've got.

(There's also the now-deprecated [POSIX regex extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php), but you should not use them any longer.  They are slower, less featureful, and most important, they aren't Unicode-safe.  Modern PCRE versions understand Unicode very well, even if PHP itself is ignorant about it.)

---

With regard to the backslash-escaping nightmare, you can keep the horror to a minimum by using single quotes to enclose the string containing the regex instead of doubles, and picking an appropriate delimiter.  Compare:

```
"/^http:\\/\\/www.foo.bar\\/index.html\\?/"
```

versus

```
'!^http://www.foo.bar/index.html\?!'
```

Inside single quotes, you only need to backslash-escape backslashes and single quotes, and picking a different delimiter avoids needing to escape the delimiter inside the regex.

Comment: The backslash-escaping nightmare can be reduced if you use a **delimiter that's not present inside the regex** -- it'll mean less escaping to do ;;; typically, when using regex on an URL or a path, using `/` as a delimiter is not quite a good idea ^^ ;;; see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: `ereg` is deprecated? I must be old.

Comment: you can use different delimiters to avoid escaping all the backslashes if you like `preg_match('%http://www\.stackthepack\.com/%',$url)`

Comment: @Pascal, I was referencing the need to backslash-escape backslashes in certain circumstances, like using double-quotes around the pattern instead of single-quotes.  Picking the right delimiter is always a good idea.

Comment: @Jared, they deprecated it in 5.3.  They did so because the next major version of PHP was *supposed* to have complete Unicode support, and the old POSIX extension couldn't be brought up to the needed standard. While the current Unicode plans have been scrapped, they left it deprecated in 5.3.

Comment: @Charles - I'm not old, just horribly out of step with nonexistent plans? Sounds about right. :) Thanks for the information, too.

Comment: +1 @jared it's depreciated...i was in the same boat with you when it happen...everything i did was in `ereg`

Comment: I don't understand how either of you managed to *stand* POSIX regexes.  :)  I came from Perl and always found them so ... limiting.  Anyway, updated my post with a backslashy nightmare example.

Comment: @kjy112 - I don't actually use regex's often (it's an allergy, really), but when I did, I used ereg. PHP didn't need both, really, but often I can find ways to use str_replace or strpos to get the same affect (short of pattern matching requirements, which are more validity checks).

Comment: @Charles - Maybe that's why I always disliked regex? :P

Answer (score 0):

:)

```
if(substr($example, 0, 1) == " "){ echo 'whitespace!';}
```

You should not be using regexp when it is not needed.

Comment: But that doesn't match newline, tabs, etc.

Comment: Well I think it can be done using ord(10) etc but regexp is the right way of course. I took question literally, sorry. @Charles answered what was asked.

Comment: this was just an example as my pseudo $example suggested.  It was more of an education question than a, "here's what I need to do" question.  I agree, no regex when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There would also be the microoptimization option:

```
if (strstr(" \t\r\n", $example{0})) {
```

The `{0}` is an outdated way to get the first character (same as `[0]` actually). And `strstr` simply checks if the character is contained in the list of whitespace characters. Another option would be `strspn`, at least in your example case.